# malloc() breaking loop

Tags: c, heap-memory

Why the code below shows directly the heap occupied by Mb:

```
int Mb = 0;
while ( malloc(1<<20)) ++Mb;
printf("Allocated %d Mb total\n", Mb);
```

What is meant by `1<<20`?

Comment: Prepare for the answer madness.

Comment: +1 @NikosC.  I'm looking forward to the follow-up questions "Why is my program an infinite loop?" or "Why doesn't this program produce any output?"

Comment: The title is in spectacular mismatch with the question you are actually asking.

Comment: Available virtual memory space != available heap memory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What is meant by `1<<20`?

A 1, shifted to the left by 20 places, also known as 2^20 = 1048576. `<<` is the bit-shift operator that shifts to the left.

Answer (score 6):

It means `2^20` which is 1 MB. So it counts the number of MBs

Comment: Just to add: you're allocating 1MB because ``malloc(size_t size)`` allocates ``size`` _bytes_ (``1MB = 2^20`` Bytes). I was confused for a moment with the units ;)

Answer (score 2):

It's a bitwise left shift operator. It means it's taking one bit (binary 00000001 for example, except with 31 leading 0) and then shifting that bit left 20 positions, leaving you with 2^20.

Answer (score 0):

On a modern operating system with virtual memory (e.g. most Unixes, Linux, Windows), this code would actually show you what the limit of the virtual memory size or the overcommit limit (whichever comes first) is and not the heap allocation size. It is constantly allocating more memory without touching it, creating a small memory leak while doing so (unless `malloc` is one of the debug variants that preinitialise the allocated memory; then, if running on Linux, the OOM killer might kill it even before it reaches the `printf`)

On a (possibly modern) operating system without virtual memory, it will show you how much memory you could allocate before the system runs out of memory and everything crashes and burns ungracefully.

Answer (score 0):

This will print you the value of MB every time it is changed

> int Mb = 0;
>
> > while ( malloc(1<<20))
> >
> > > printf("Allocated %d Mb total\n", ++Mb);

1 << 20 is the value of 1 Megabyte (e.g. means 2^20 ): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megabyte

Answer (score 0):

About "Why the code below shows directly the heap occupied by Mb"

```
int Mb = 0;
while ( malloc(1<<20)) ++Mb;
printf("Allocated %d Mb total\n", Mb);
What is meant by 1<<20?
```

Your are counting the number of times that [`malloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) returns a not null value when trying to allocate 1MB (2^20 bytes, other answers discuss shift operator). Dynamicaly reserved memory is allocated in the heap, so it's counting the number of MB the heap has available.

Although I'm not sure about the precision of this estimation, since `malloc` does not just moves a pointer in the exactly indicated size.